# user can't login using CodeIgniter with facebook php sdk

Tags: codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, facebook

I am following the guide [here](http://www.betterhelpworld.com/codeigniter/how-to-use-facebook-php-sdk-v-3-0-0-with-codeigniter) to play around with the facebook php sdk, but my little app doesn't work. It keeps staying on the login page.

Here is the controller:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Facebook_connect extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
        $this->load->library('fb_connect');
    }

    function index()
    {

    }

    function test()
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Facebook API Testing';

        $data['user_id'] = $this->fb_connect->user_id;
        if($data['user_id'])
        {
            $data['user_profile'] = $this->fb_connect->user;
        }
        if($data['user_id'])
        {
            $data['logout_url'] = $this->fb_connect->getLogoutUrl();;
        }
        else
        {
            $data['login_url'] = $this->fb_connect->getLoginUrl();
        }

        $this->template->load('template', 'facebook_connect/test', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

Here is the view:

```
<h1>php-sdk</h1>

<?php if($user_id): ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $logout_url; ?>">Logout</a>
<?php else: ?>
  <div>
    Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
    <a href="<?php echo $login_url; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
  </div>
<?php endif ?>

<h3>PHP Session</h3>
<pre><?php print_r($_SESSION); ?></pre>

<?php if($user_id): ?>
  <h3>Your Avata</h3>
  <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user_id; ?>/picture">

  <h3>Your User Object (/me)</h3>
  <pre><?php print_r($user_profile); ?></pre>
<?php else: ?>
  <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
<?php endif ?>
```

I get stuck at it and couldn't figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this example provided by facebook:
https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php

But keep your `$this->load->library('fb_connect');` and make sure to add `$this->fb_connect` to any facebook library calls in that example.

It works 100%. Try to just put all the code in the controller to make sure it works, then distribute as needed. Not sure what your problem is, perhaps faulty return url.